# CKEDITOR Copying images from word

Tags: ms-word, ckeditor

When I copy paste from word on to CKEDITOR I am able to maintain the formatting and styles but the images do not get copied.It works fine when I copy from the browser. Is this because Word stores the images at the local system?

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you use IE11 you can get the images pasted. In Firefox and Chrome, the images are kept as references to the local filesystem and so the page can't access them.

The only option that I know to (besides doing all the steps manually) is to use the [ImagesFromWord plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/imagesfromword) that helps greatly to get those images uploaded to your server.